# How can I *efficiently* generate a tuple of all types from a nested expression?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have some template expression that contains an arrangement of types, in this case they from an [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree):

```
template <typename... Children>                                                    
struct Branch                                                                      
{                                                                                  
};                                                                                 

template <int param>                                                               
struct Leaf                                                                        
{                                                                                  
};
```

The input expression could be any nested combination of `Branch` and `Leaf` types, but to keep it simple I'll create a linear AST that contains a single `Leaf` wrapped `N` layers deep in `Branch` types:

```
using Expression =
  Branch<
    Branch<
      Leaf>>; // N = 2
```

For the sake of this question I've created a function that generates these expressions on the fly, so I can demonstrate the problem I am having with plots. So here is the function that I'll use to generate my expressions:

```
// wrap Leaf in Branch N number of times:
template <int N, typename T = Leaf>
struct Nest
{
    using type = typename Nest<N-1, Branch<T>>::type;
};

template <typename T>
struct Nest<0, T>
{
    using type = T;
};
```

[Live example for N = 25](http://ideone.com/T5ioOZ)

**Note that the solution should work for *any* combination of branches and leaves, including multiple branch/leaf combinations per branch, and not just for the limited set created by `Nest`.** I just use `Nest` so that I can generate the plots below without manually writing out huge expressions.
Now, my question is, how do I *efficiently* extract from this expression all instantiated `Branch` types?

So for `N == 2`, as shown above, I would want the following as the output:

```
std::tuple<
  Branch<Branch<Leaf>>,
  Branch<Leaf>>;
```

It doesn't have to be a tuple, it could be anything, but it *does* have to be able to accept any number of types without serious hackery, so `boost::mpl` types are out of the question, at least as at `Boost 1.56`. I'll use a tuple for the sake of this question.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
namespace detail
{

// a container of types
template <typename... T> struct Types {};

template <typename T, typename Enabled = void>
struct UnfoldImpl;

template <template <typename...> class Branch, typename... Children>
struct UnfoldImpl<
    Types<Branch<Children...>>,
    typename std::enable_if<Branch<Children...>::IsBranch::value>::type>
{
    using type = typename TupleCat<
        std::tuple<Types<Branch<Children...>>>,
        typename UnfoldImpl<Types<Children...>>::type>::type;
};

template <typename Leaf>
struct UnfoldImpl<
    Types<Leaf>,
    typename std::enable_if<!Leaf::IsBranch::value>::type>
{
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template <typename FirstBranch, typename... OtherBranches>
struct UnfoldImpl<Types<FirstBranch, OtherBranches...>,typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(OtherBranches)>::type>
{
    using type = typename TupleCat<
        typename UnfoldImpl<Types<FirstBranch>>::type,
        typename UnfoldImpl<Types<OtherBranches...>>::type>::type;
};

}

// Take an expression containing some combination of branch and leaf classes, and extract every
// type that is a template instantiation of Branch and place it into a tuple.
template <typename Expression>
struct Unfold : detail::UnfoldImpl<detail::Types<Expression>> {};
```

The complete program, which instantiates both the expression and then the branch types, [can be seen here](http://ideone.com/RJTqCr).

My implementation of `Unfold` works, but it seems to be horrendously inefficient. Below is the total resident memory during compilation using GCC 4.9.1 with only the `std=c++11` flag, using the command `time -v g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`:

[image: Peak resident memory vs expression depth]

The red line represents the peak resident memory during compilation (as measured by `time -v gcc ...`) from generating the expression only (ie. instantiating a type `Nest<N>::type` in `main()`), and the blue line represents adding to this an instantiation of type `Unfold<Expression>::type` where `Expression` is the output of `Nest<N>`.

I am delighted that the red line appears constant, indicating that the compiler is probably doing a decent job here. However, the blue line is clearly polynomial, and I was wondering if there were any easy way of bringing that down, ideally to linear, although `Nlog(N)` would also be great.

**My question is: How can I improve the efficiency of `Unfold` to something better than O(N^2)?**

I asked a general form of this question already ([How can I reduce the compile-time memory footprint of large templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415909/how-can-i-reduce-the-compile-time-memory-footprint-of-large-templates)) but I'm having trouble applying those solutions to this particular case and would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: You need to give the whole command line so that I can invoke `gcc` on something like coliru.

Comment: @Puppy `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`

Comment: I don't believe that produces a swirly graph.

Comment: Or to put it bluntly: Given your code, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Puppy, oh right, I misunderstood. I ran `/usr/bin/time -v g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp` to get the resident memory for every input argument `N` to `Nest<N>` in the code shown in [the linked example](http://ideone.com/RJTqCr). I didn't run a script to generate the plot; I modified the number each time and plotted it manually in `LibreOffice`.

Comment: "ideally to linear"
I think you meant constant, not linear. Or else it doesn't make sense to refer to logarithmic complexity as "also great", compared to linear.

Comment: Then you need to remove the graph and add the timings, and produce a test script that runs the compilation for each value you're interested in.

Comment: @Loopunroller no that wasn't a mistake. I am saying that the complexity is polynomial, so I'd be happy for linear or logarithmic. Constant is not possible.

Comment: @quant In that case, you want to ideally bring it down to logarithmic complexity. Not linear.

Comment: @Loopunroller ah I see, yes, fixed.

Comment: @Puppy I've got the timings, they're the same shape (O(N^2)) but timing isn't a primary concern. I don't see why it's necessary to provide a script; I'm just interested in a solution that reduces the complexity of my `Unfold` algorithm from N^2 to something better...

Comment: Would this question be better suited to Code Review? I figured since it's not actual code and just a confined example it might be ok on SO, but now I'm not sure...

Comment: @quant: Because there's no way in hell that I, C++ programmer, am going to Bash script a thing that checks whether or not my C++ code meets your requirements. Er, by timings I meant memory use, or whatever your graph is of. All I'm saying is, you're asking for C++ help, but if I write a C++ program, the function of my compiler is not enough, and you should provide everything required to go from source code + compiler to "Did this solve the problem? yes/no".

Comment: @Puppy, I think you misunderstand my question. I am asking for a way of reducing the complexity of an algorithm (in this case `Fold<N>`, from N^2 to something better), I don't want the answer to include a plot! I only provided the plot to illustrate that the complexity of my implementation is indeed polynomial. My intention was to make the question _clearer_ with the plot but clearly I've failed!

Comment: @dyp, yes it does! I've added a plot with your suggestion. Feel free to add it as the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @quant Nevermind, it does not handle multiple branches. Your test case is too simple ;)

Comment: @dyp oh... right. I thought that might happen. This was a really hard question to form, because I wanted to keep it as simple as possible yet still _describe_ the problem. I'm thinking I should have put it on Code Review instead...

Comment: Ah, I'm too tired to do this correctly right now. But it is possible to create a constant amount of types for each node of the tree, I think. Something along the lines of: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e967b43cf2defc30

Comment: I made [this solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad6c9828f8661904) out of what @dyp created. I don't think it's possible to flatten n-ary type list in constant number of types, but this should be probably good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The golden rule is simplification. And don't use `tuple`.

```
template <typename...> struct type_list {using type = type_list;};

template<typename...>
struct cat_type_list;

template<typename T>
struct cat_type_list<T> : T {};

template<typename... T, typename... U, typename... R>
struct cat_type_list<type_list<T...>, type_list<U...>, R...> :
    cat_type_list<type_list<T..., U...>, R...> {};


template <typename... AllBranches>
struct Unfold
{
    using type = typename cat_type_list<
        typename Unfold<AllBranches>::type...>::type;
};

template <typename T>
struct Unfold<T>
{
    using type = type_list<>;
};

template <template <typename...> class Branch, typename... Children>
struct Unfold<Branch<Children...>>
{
    using type = typename cat_type_list<
        type_list<Branch<Children...>>,
        typename Unfold<Children...>::type>::type;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f006e8432b33f0f7). The time needed to compile doubles from ~150 to 320ms once I take `N` as ~`500` instead of `50`.

And here is a wonderful chart showing the peak memory usage of GCC when compiling the program - values were collected by `for lim in {5..800..5}; do /usr/local/bin/time -f"%M" g++ -DLIMIT=$lim -std=c++11 ~/Programming/Saves/TEMPS/TEMP2.cxx; done`:

[image]

The space complexity seems linear to me.